# Do not show first option is selected in angular

Tags: angular, select, angular7

Unable to show default option.

```
 <select class="form-control search-head" [(ngModel)]="categoryId">
   <option disabled value="1" [selected]=true>Choose Category</option>
   <option [value]="category._id" *ngFor="let category of categories">{{category.parent.details.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

how to show choose category is selected when page is loaded

Comment: What exactly you want to ask?

Comment: now i edit our question please help

Comment: assign 1 to categoryId e.g. categoryId = 1, If you set as categoryId null or undefined then it is replace in your options

Answer (score 1):

here is [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qmh51u) for you 
.ts

```
months: string[] = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

constructor()
{
this.selected_month="Feb";

 }
}
```

in html

```
<select class="form-control search-head" [(ngModel)]="selected_month">
   <!-- <option disabled value="1" [selected]=true>Choose Category</option> -->
   <option [value]="m" *ngFor="let m of months">{{m}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: If its helps and working please accept ancwer it is good for futur users